# Count group by with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My DB schema looks like this:

```
User table

Shop table (foreign_key to User)

Item-Shop join table (foreign key to Item, foreign key to Shop)

Item table
```

So, a User has many items through shops.

I am trying to find out the number of items each user has, knowing that a User can have several shops, and each shop can have several Item.

What would be the SQL query that I would need to do for this? So, at the end I would expect something like:

```
User ID       Item count
 1                30
 2                50
 3                70
```

Comment: `Join`, `Group By` and `Count` -- depending on your desired results, you may want to use `Distinct` as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to get the amount of items related to a user you will have to join the different tables and using a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause:

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(i.item_id) item_count FROM user u
INNER JOIN shop s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN item_shop vis ON vis.shop_id = s.shop_id
INNER JOIN item i ON i.item_id = vis.item_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

If you also would like to return user who doesn't have any items yet (`item_count` will be 0), you will need to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead.

If we have the following sample data:

```
+---------+ +---------+---------+ +---------+---------+ +---------+
| user_id | | shop_id | user_id | | item_id | shop_id | | item_id |
+---------+ +---------+---------+ +---------+---------+ +---------+
|       1 | |       1 |       1 | |       1 |       1 | |       1 |
|       2 | |       2 |       2 | |       2 |       2 | |       2 |
|       4 | |       2 |       1 | |       3 |       2 | |       3 |
+---------+ +---------+---------+ |       4 |       1 | |       4 |
                                  |       5 |       1 | |       5 |
                                  +---------+---------+ +---------+
```

You will get the following result:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | item_count |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          5 |
|       2 |          2 |
+---------+------------+
```